# SQL Server 2016 - How to select integer array from JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I received a valid JSON string from client side, it contains an array of integer values:

```
declare @JSON nvarchar(max) = N'{"Comments": "test", "Markets": [3, 151]}'
```

How to select the market IDs correctly?

If I use a query like this: `select * from openjson(@JSON) j`, it returns

[image]

The type of Markets is 4, which means an object,
but the query below returns null value:
`select j.Markets from openjson(@JSON) with(Markets nvarchar(max)) j`

My goal is to update `Market` table based on these IDs, eg:
`update Market set Active = 1 where MarketID in (3, 151)`

Is there a way to do this?
Any built-in function compatible with SQL server 2016 can be used.

---

**Note:**
Thanks to @johnlbevan
`SELECT VALUE FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.Markets')` works perfectly for this problem.

Just for the completeness, here is how I created the JSON integer array (`"Markets": [3, 151]`) from SQL server.
Since there is no `array_agg` function out of the box in 2016, I did this:

```
SELECT (
  JSON_QUERY('[' + STUFF(( SELECT ',' + CAST(MarketID AS VARCHAR)
  FROM Market
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']' ) AS Markets)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand the Markets array alongside other columns you can do this:

```
SELECT Comments, Market
FROM OPENJSON('{"Comments": "test", "Markets": [3, 151]}')
WITH (Comments nvarchar(32), Markets NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) AS a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (a.Markets) WITH (Market INT '$') AS b
```

- Convert the string to json
- Map the first field returned to the `Comments` column with type `nvarchar(32)`
- Map the second field to `Markets` column with type `nvarchar(max)`, then use `as json` to say that the contents is json (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql#arguments for a more detailed description - search the page for `as json`; the key paragraph starts at the 4th occurrence)
- Use a `cross apply` to apply the OPENJSON function to the Markets column so we can fetch values from that property.
- Finally use the `WITH` statement to map the name `Market` to the returned value, and assign it a data type of `INT`.

However, to just get the list of values needed to do the update, you can do this:

```
UPDATE Market
SET Active = 1
WHERE MarketID IN
(
    SELECT value
    FROM OPENJSON('{"Comments": "test", "Markets": [3, 151]}','$.Markets')
);
```

- Again OPENJSON lets us query the string as JSON
- However this time we specify a path to point at the Markets value directly (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql)
- We now return the `value`s returned and filter our UPDATE on those, as we would were we dealing with any other subquery.

Comment: Wow, I see what's going on. I was missing the `AS JSON` part, so I got `null` from `Markets`. Thank you

Comment: No worries.  ps. If you wanted the first query (i.e. where you're getting other columns too) you may want to switch the `cross apply` for an `outer apply` depending on how you'd want things to behave when markets is an empty array.  Don't think that applies in your current use case though.